# How to draw normal of segments in unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to draw normal of the segments in a curve within the unity editor. So far I have calculated the normals, but when I draw it in unity editor, its direction is not correct. I think I am missing something in the Draw function. Here is the short version of the code.

```c#
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Segments : MonoBehaviour
{
    [HideInInspector]
    public List<Vector3> ControlPoints;
    [HideInInspector]
    public List<Vector3> Normals;

    [HideInInspector]
    public bool initialized;

    public void Init()
    {
        ControlPoints = new List<Vector3>();

        ControlPoints.Add(new Vector3(40, 0, 0));
        ControlPoints.Add(new Vector3(30, 0, -30));
        ControlPoints.Add(new Vector3(0, 0, -40));
        ControlPoints.Add(new Vector3(-30, 0, -30));
        ControlPoints.Add(new Vector3(-40, 0, 0));
        ControlPoints.Add(new Vector3(-30, 0, 30));
        ControlPoints.Add(new Vector3(0, 0, 40));
        ControlPoints.Add(new Vector3(30, 0, 30));

        int points = ControlPoints.Count;
        Normals = new List<Vector3>();

        for (int i = 0; i < points; i++)
        {
            //if we define dx=x2-x1 and dy=y2-y1, then the normals are (-dy, dx) and (dy, -dx).
            Vector2 start = new Vector2(ControlPoints[i % points].x, ControlPoints[i % points].z);
            Vector2 end = new Vector2(ControlPoints[(i + 1) % points].x, ControlPoints[(i + 1) % points].z);
            Vector2 direction = (end - start).normalized;
            Normals.Add(new Vector3(-direction.y, direction.x, 0));
        }

        initialized = true;
    }
}



using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomEditor(typeof(Segments))]
public class DrawSegments : Editor
{
    Segments segments;

    void OnSceneGUI()
    {
        Draw();
    }

    void OnEnable()
    {
        segments = (Segments)target;
        if (!segments.initialized)
        {
            segments.Init();
        }
    }

    void Draw()
    {
        int points = segments.ControlPoints.Count;
        Handles.color = Color.green;

        for (int i = 0; i < points; i++)
        {
            Handles.FreeMoveHandle(segments.ControlPoints[i], Quaternion.identity, 1f, Vector3.zero, Handles.RectangleHandleCap);
            Handles.DrawLine(segments.ControlPoints[i % points], segments.ControlPoints[(i + 1) % points]);

            if (points > 1)
            {
                Vector3 midPoint = (segments.ControlPoints[i % points] + segments.ControlPoints[(i + 1) % points]) / 2;
                Handles.DrawLine(midPoint, midPoint + segments.Normals[i] + Vector3.one * 10);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is how it is coming in the unity editor
[image: This how it is coming in the unity editor]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the drawer it should be

```c#
Handles.DrawLine(midPoint, midPoint + Normals[i] * 10);
```

what you did by using `+ Vector3.one * 10` is always additionally shifting the direction in X and Y direction.

---

Then you would rather use [`Vector3.Cross`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Cross.html) in order to get Vectors that stand in a 90° angle on your `direction` vector.

Since you are forcing the vertices to be always co-planar in XZ anyway (in your code you used `Vector2` in order to cut off the Y component) can directly pass both positions to `Vector3.Cross` so you will get the normal of a triangle using `Vector3.zero` as one vertice.

For the first point the `% points` is actually always redundant.

```c#
for (int i = 0; i < points; i++)
{
    Normals.Add(Vector3.Cross(ControlPoints[i], ControlPoints[(i + 1) % points]).normalized);
}
```

[image]

Depending a bit on your needs you will have to be careful however in which order you pass in both points. Since the "left hand" rule is applied the normal would flip its direction if the order of both vectors is flipped in 3D space.

> The cross product of two vectors results in a third vector which is perpendicular to the two input vectors. The result's magnitude is equal to the magnitudes of the two inputs multiplied together and then multiplied by the sine of the angle between the inputs. You can determine the direction of the result vector using the "left hand rule".
>
> [image]

**However, - again - since you are forcing them to be always co-planar in XZ is it actually not already clear that every normal will always equal `Vector3.up` anyway? So that you could skip the entire normal calculation and simply do**

```c#
Handles.DrawLine(midPoint, midPoint + Vector3.up * 10);
```

---

Btw: You don't need a CustomEditor for this. You can simply do it in `OnDrawGizmos` or `OnDrawGizmosSelected` (only called when object or parent is selected in the hierarchy)

```c#
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    private void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
    {
        if (!initialized)
        {
            Init();
        }

        var points = ControlPoints.Count;
        Handles.color = Color.green;

        for (var i = 0; i < points; i++)
        {
            Handles.FreeMoveHandle(ControlPoints[i], Quaternion.identity, 1f, Vector3.zero, Handles.RectangleHandleCap);
            Handles.DrawLine(ControlPoints[i], ControlPoints[(i + 1) % points]);

            if (points > 1)
            {
                var midPoint = (ControlPoints[i] + ControlPoints[(i + 1) % points]) / 2;
                Handles.DrawLine(midPoint, midPoint + Normals[i] * 10);
            }
        }
    }
#endif
```

Comment: Actually I have created script to draw curve in the editor and there is a lot more code in the draw function, this was just a short version. Anyways thanks for you time and effort for helping me out. I will try your solution.

Comment: Your code also producing the same result. I guess calculating normal is not the problem although use of vector3.cross is elegant and clean. But it is still not drawing normals properly.

Comment: Just added a fix regarding the drawer. did you reset the according component? Otherwise `Init` will never be called again

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Vector3.one * 10 was the problem. How silly mistake. And yes, Init will never be called again in this code chunk. But since I am adding more point in the curve from editor and even edit it in the full code, it is getting updated properly.